# Layout of gantt chart with linkedTo series

Tags: highcharts

I need to show actual vs planned in a gantt chart. Here is an example:

[image]

with code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/alpic80/geqh6fav/6/). The narrower line represents the planned details for the task. I need to change some options that are series based and so used a 2nd series with linkedTo but now the rendering is incorrect. Here is the example:
[image]

with code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/alpic80/054uvh93/)

```
 }, {
"linkedTo": "main",
"data": [{
  "name": "Generate proofs",
  "id": "_dq3hkMWXEeeTdKTuQU2hRA_planned",
  "parent": "_dqbcsMWXEeeTdKTuQU2hRA",
  "start": 1578355200000,
  "end": 1581638400000,
  "pointWidth": 3,
  "color": "red"
}]
```

How can I avoid the split and the loss of the last category.

Comment: Hi @Alain P, Do you want to achieve something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k3681c7w/ ?

Comment: What I want to achieve is just like the 1st image, but using independent series.

Comment: It looks that is not currently possible. Here is a reprted bug on Highcharts repository: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11796